# How to make a laravel view that uses data from a controller but also still allows the controller to output raw JSON?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have a controller that outputs data from the database in raw JSON format.

I want this to function as an API and allow anyone to make views with any technology that can consume the JSON i.e. Angular, Jquery/Ajax.

However I also want to make a view in Laravel.

So what's the best practice for creating a view from Laravel that uses data from a controller while still allowing the controller to output raw JSON?

The options I'm thinking of are to call the controller from the view(not good?) or to create extra routes.

Comment: You're saying that you want to have a page at a single URL that can either be a view or output raw JSON?

Comment: Haha. Yeah that kind of put it in perspective for me.   So extra routes it is. Thanks.

Comment: It really depends...you could use one route and use a query string `?json=true` etc.  I think this is an opinion based question.

Comment: I really just want separation of concerns.  My data at one URL and my view at another url harnessing that data.  
It seems if both the view and data are generated by Laravel there's some easier way to do it than making two http requests.

Answer (score 0):

```php
Route::get('sample', function ()
{
    $data = getDataFromSomewhere();

    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        return Response::json($data);
    }

    return View::make('some.view', compact('data))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate API controllers, but you could do something like this if you want one controller to handle all response formats:

**URL:**

```
mySite.com/getData?output=json
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{

    $data = MyModel::all();

    switch(Request::query('output')){
        case 'json':
            return Response::json($data, $this->responseCode, $this->accessControl);
        case 'xml':
            return Response::make($data, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        default:
            return View::make('data.myData', compact($data));
    }

}
```